# Try to access URL parameter inside razor page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I send an URL through an email to access a form with the parameter name "email". I try to access the email parameter inside the razor page.

This is what I pass as URL:

> https://localhost:44339/Home/LecturerRegister?email=pasindu@gmail.com'

Then I access the email parameter by using `ViewContext.RouteData.Values["email"]`

```
<input type="email" required class="form-control" name="Email" value="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["email"])">
```

But I can't access the parameter value by this method. It's return nothing.

Comment: Try this: `@(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["email"])`

Comment: RouteData is for values that are passed as segments of a URL, not as query string values.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to work with data passed in URLs is to use *Model Binding*. In this example, you should add a public property to your PageModel class representing the email and mark it with the `BindProperty` attribute, opting in to binding in GET requests:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet=true)]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Then use an input tag helper to  generate your input, assigning the public the `asp-for` attribute:

```
<input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
```

the tar will take case of generating the correct name and attributes and will assign the value from the bound property.

More about model binding in Razor Pages: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding
More about input tag helpers: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/tag-helpers/input-tag-helper

Note: you could also use `Request.Query["email"]`, but model binding is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
value="@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["email"].ToString()"
```

Comment: It's not a route data value. It's a query string value.